# Vite did not Work Properly loading asset on laravel 9 in cpanel server?

Tags: laravel, cpanel, breeze, vite

Vite didn't load assets properly on my laravel 9 project. I've been facing this problem when using laravel 9 with Vite. At first when I install laravel breeze I though the breeze is the problem, now I try using breeze login. please see the screenshot below. can someone help me?[image: dindt see css with vite]

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Did you run build?

Comment: this is a URL 
https://carrentalunion.com/login